# Git hub: I added a file but I want to exclude it from my next commit

Tags: git, version-control, github

I am new to git hub, I added a file by mistake but I dont want it to be there the next time I commit.. 
How do I view the files that are to be committed next time? and how do I exclude files?

And in general, any recommendations for tutorials for using git hub and its commands (their official tutorials are horrible)? or any user friendly gui? I have been using cvs and svn for 3 years and I've never suffered that much from a version control system before!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would like to unstage the file, e.g. revert to before you did the

```
$ git add not_commit.file
```

simple remove it from the staging area with

```
$ git rm --cached not_commit.file
```

Answer (score 1):

http://book.git-scm.com/4_ignoring_files.html

Thats the process for telling git to ignore/exclude a file. Also the documentation isn't too bad.

To view what files will be commited you should run git status before a commit.

Tbh I find git very easy to use if I follow this process....

```
git status // check what you're about to commit
git add . // add everything (if thats what you want)
git commit -a // commit everything
git pull // make sure you're up to date
git push // push your changes
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Oh and I think Gitty (free) and Tower (paid app) are popular GUIs for git.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the file first (from the index only, not from the working directory, in other word not from your disk).
Then you add it to the `.gitignore` file.

```
git rm --cached -- local/path/to/theFile
echo local/path/to/theFile > .gitignore
git add .gitignore
git commit -m "ignore now local/path/to/theFile"
```

From now on, it won't ever be part of your next commits.

[`git rm`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rm.html) man page:

```
--cached
```

> Use this option to unstage and remove paths only from the index.
>   Working tree files, whether modified or not, will be left alone.